# Where does internal exception in Kafka Streams come from?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I am encountering a problem when trying to aggregate a KGroupedStream< String, TsdbObject >
where TsdbObject is a POJO that has a method `Double getValue()`.  The following statements
show the groupBy and attempted aggregation:

```
KGroupedStream< String, TsdbObject > assets_grouped_by_parents =
    kstream.groupBy( group_by_parent_mapper, Serialized.with( Serdes.String(), tsdb_object_serde ) );

KTable< String, Double > sums_of_groups_by_parents = 
    assets_grouped_by_parents.aggregate( new SummerInitializer(), new SummerAggregator() );
```

The aggregation is done by the following classes:

```
private class SummerAggregator implements Aggregator< String, TsdbObject, Double > {
    @Override
        public Double apply(String key, TsdbObject value, Double aggregate) {
    System.out.println( "SummerAggregator.apply:  key is " + key + ", value is " + value +
                ", aggregate is " + aggregate );
    return aggregate + value.getValue();
    }
}

private class SummerInitializer implements Initializer< Double > {
    @Override
        public Double apply() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println( "SummerInitializer" );
    return 0.0;
    }
}
```

When I execute the application, I get the following exception:

```
Encountered the following error during processing: 
java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
    at com.ui.kafka.experiments.metrics.TsdbObjectRollUp$SummerAggregator.apply(TsdbObjectRollUp.java:1)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamAggregate$KStreamAggregateProcessor.process(KStreamAggregate.java:79)
```

The referenced line in`KStreamAggregate` is:

```
// try to add the new new value
if (value != null) {
    newAgg = aggregator.apply(key, value, newAgg);
}
```

The strange thing is that the value of `newAgg`, which is supposed to be a Double, is:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 21]
```

which certainly isn't castable to a Double.  **Where did this weird value come from?**

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in an `DoubleSerde` for the result value type of `assets_grouped_by_parents.aggregate(...)` using the optional parameter `Materialized.withValueSerde()`:

```java
KTable<String, Double> sums_of_groups_by_parents = 
    assets_grouped_by_parents.aggregate(
        new SummerInitializer(),
        new SummerAggregator(),
        Materialized.withValueSerde(Serdes.DoubleSerde()));
```

You might also need to specify the `StringSerde` for the key, if it's not set as default serde in the config.

Comment: Matthias, thanks.   I ended up using:

    KTable< String, Double > sums_of_groups_by_parents = 
        assets_grouped_by_parents.aggregate( new SummerInitializer(), new SummerAggregator(),Materialized.with( Serdes.String(), Serdes.Double())  );